# We don't support this API version. Use API version 32.0 or later to retrieve this process

Tags: deployment, process-builder, flow, migration-tool

I'm using the Salesforce Migration Tool (Ant) to deploy Salesforce changes. When I retrieve my changes, all changes are pulled down (even other flows/processes) except for one, which throws this warning/error:

```
retrieveCode:
[sf:retrieve] Request for a retrieve submitted successfully.
[sf:retrieve] Request ID for the current retrieve task: 09Sq0000005aYGYEA8
[sf:retrieve] Waiting for server to finish processing the request...
[sf:retrieve] Request Status: Pending
[sf:retrieve] Request Status: Succeeded
[sf:retrieve] Retrieve warnings (1):
[sf:retrieve] package.xml - We don't support this API version. Use API version 32.0 or later to retrieve this process: My_Fancy_Process-18
[sf:retrieve] Finished request 09Sq0000005aYGYEA8 successfully.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 12 seconds
```

This message is grossly vague, and I'm not finding a single hit about it on the web.

I verified I am using version 38.0 of the `ant-salesforce.jar` file. My `package.xml` version is 36.0.

Does anyone know how to get past this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it turns out, I needed to update my `package.xml` version to `38.0`. After doing so, the process retrieved fine.

I cannot say for sure but I believe the issue was due to the offending process being marked as `Invocable`, which may be incompatible with version `36.0` of the API.

Comment: Yes, for invocable flows need API 32+ and for invocable processes need API 38+ https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_action.meta/api_action/actions_obj_flow.htm

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a metadata component that your package.xml has reference which is of version higher than 32 and your ANT jar is still using version 32 or other reason could be your package.xml file has version as 32 specified .

The resolution would be update your ANT jar library to recent version if jar is not latest and if package.xml is using version 32 just bump the version of the jar to 35 or 36 and you should be good .

Comment: Thanks Mohith, that was my first thought as well, however I verified I am using version 38 of the `ant-salesforce.jar` file. My `package.xml` version is 36.0.